# How to call one api constantly with some delay and also destroy its calling manually?

Tags: angular, typescript, delay, angular-services

I am trying to design a chatting app using angular and Django-rest-framework.

I need to class get_messge API constantly with some delay.

I try this but didn't think it is a good idea

```
get_messages()
  {
    const uid1:any = localStorage.getItem('uid');
    const uid2:any = this.msg_to_id;
    this.userService.get_messages(uid1,uid2).subscribe((response:any)=>{
      console.warn(response);
      this.message_arr = response.resp;
      setTimeout(() => {
      }, 3000);
      this.get_messages();
    },(error)=>{
      console.warn(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure about the question exactly. Why dont you use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`?

Comment: Give following error in browser```ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Subscription -> Subscription -> Subscription]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Subscription!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Subscription -> Subscription -> Subscription]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Subscription!
   ```

Comment: That looks like you added `Subscription` to the constructor as if it was a dependency injected class. If that is correct, you need to remove it. just an `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs'` is enough

Answer (score 1):

You could try `timer`. this creates an observable that emits after every duration you specify infinitely. Just make sure to unsubscribe.

To automatically destroy, you can add a reference to the `subscribe` and call `unsubscribe` on `ngOnDestroy` hook

```js
private currentSub: Subscription;
// ...
ngOnInit () {
  this.get_message()
}
// ...
ngOnDestroy () {
  this.currentSub?.unsubscribe()
}
// ...
get_messages() {
  const uid1:any = localStorage.getItem('uid');
  const uid2:any = this.msg_to_id;
  this.currentSub = timer(3000).pipe(
    mergeMap(() => this.userService.get_messages(uid1,uid2))
  ).subscribe((response:any)=>{
    console.warn(response);
    this.message_arr = response.resp;
  },(error)=>{
    console.warn(error);
  });
}
```

If you want it to call the api immediately, change the `timer` to have 2 parameters like this: `timer(0, 3000)`. 0 is the first delay and 3000 is the delay on the next emits.

- mergeMap is for switching to another observable. Better explained here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap

For something closer to what you have, which starts waiting only after a call is done, maybe calling the setTimeout in complete callback of `subscribe` is better.

```js
private currentSub: Subscription;
destroyed = false;
// ...
ngOnInit () {
  this.get_message()
}
// ...
ngOnDestroy () {
  this.currentSub?.unsubscribe()
}
get_messages()
{
    if (this.destroyed) { return }
    const uid1:any = localStorage.getItem('uid');
    const uid2:any = this.msg_to_id;
    this.currentSub = this.userService.get_messages(uid1,uid2).subscribe((response:any)=>{
      console.warn(response);
      this.message_arr = response.resp;
    },(error)=>{
      console.warn(error);
    }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.get_messages();
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```